# Responsive Embeds using default embed shortcode

Tags: shortcode, embed, oembed

Can someone explain how to make embed shortcode responsive?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Comment: take a look at this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/responsive-video-embeds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally posted by bainternet

> take a look at this
>   [wordpress.org/extend/plugins/responsive-video-embeds](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/responsive-video-embeds/)

Thats a perfect plugin.